# Changing Text When Dragging Label UIPanGesture Get To The First Position !! Swift , IOS

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

I have Label And UIPanGestureRecognizer. When Dragging To a new position, I change the text , but it changes and go back to the default position !!

I want To Change the text and Stay In the Dragging Position

Handle Code:

```
  func handlePanGesture(panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

var translation = panGesture.translationInView(view)
panGesture.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: view)
println(translation)

label.center = CGPoint(x: label.center.x+translation.x, y: label.center.y+translation.y)
label.multipleTouchEnabled = true
label.userInteractionEnabled = true

if panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {

   label.text = "End Drag"

}}
```

Comment: If you are using autolayout, the constraints will reset the `UIView` to the old position. You will need to update the constraints on the `UIView` to reflect the new position.

Comment: Thanks @RoboticCat ,But Can You Show me some code :)

Comment: Unfortunately I have no code to share. One stack overflow post recommended watching the Autolayout videos from WWDC 2012 but there may be examples in other WWDC videos from 2013, 2014 and 2015 but I don't know for sure: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc2012/

Comment: Thanks @RoboticCat :)